# EF 7 Many-to-Many relationship no FK to connector table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework 7 RC1, I am essentially trying to create a field so that I can hold Students Standards (one student can have many standards, each standard can belong to many students). Following the asp.net docs I have the tables setup, and I filled out the Student table, the Standard table and StudentStandard table manually in SQL Server using some made up data. However, when I debug the code/view during runtime I see that the StudentStandards field is 'null' when I perform a getAll in the controller. I am accessing this field in the view using the following code: model.Students.StudentStandards.Select(c=>c.StandardId) but this doesn't provide anything.

```
    public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }

    public ICollection<StudentStandard> StudentStandards { get; set; }

}

public class StudentStandard
{
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Standard")]
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{

    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<StudentStandard> StudentStandards { get; set; }
}
```

This is what the table look like after using migrations to create it:

[image: SQL server tables and columns]

My question: how do I get this m:m relationship to store and retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to eager-load the table using the following code:

```
    context.Students
   .Include(a => a.StudentStandards)
   .ThenInclude(b => b.Standard);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is called eager-loading. By default, any EF query will fetch the records of the entity itself, but not of the foreign key tables that belong to it. If you're interested in bringing in the related tables data, you should use `Include()` function and specify the foreign key tables you are interested in, the Standards table in your case. Your EF Linq will look something like this:

```
//context is your DbContext object
context.Students.Include(s => s.Standards).ToList();
```

Comment: I can Include the StudentStandards connector table, but I don't get autosense for the Standards table as you have above. Looking at my Student entity, that does make sense because there is no Standards field per se. Can you verify for me please? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @dotNet. Figured it out using a combination of your answer and other web posts

Comment: @DerDee: Which property?

Comment: Students, so to overwrite the linktable (StudentStandards)

Comment: @DerDee: I'm really not sure what you're asking. `Studnents` property is generated against the `Student` table by the EF designer when you import model from the database.

Comment: Sorry I meant Standards, simply how to kick out a connector table/ link table, when there's a many to many relationship. In EF5 en 6 it was able to detect the function of this table, but in EF7 this wont work, you need to include and theninclude, work I don't want to do. Need a property straight to second table.

Comment: @DerDee: I haven't used EF7 yet. What you're saying, if true, would be a step backwards.

Comment: @DerDee The only way I found to do this was to use the Include and the ThenInclude - it is different from EF6. I have marked my answer using this as this is what works in EF7/EF Core 1.0

Comment: Thought the same, was surprised to see the "old" method in here. But he is trying to answer ef7 answer with ef6 knowledge...